# Force IE 11 compatibility mode for certain sites within domain

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

When setting compatibility mode in IE 11 it wants to add our whole domain (somedomain.co.uk) but we don't want every site (*.somedomain.co.uk) to be covered by this. We want just sharepoint.somedomain.co.uk and not www.somedomain.co.uk to be rendered using compatibility mode.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Group Policy to enforce compatibility view for a specific subdomain.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `gpedit.msc` and press OK to launch Group Policy Editor.

The policy can be found in Computer or User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Use Policy List of Internet Explorer 7 sites.

[image]

Comment: Does this work on IE 11? I have not been able to get it to work...

Comment: It should. We're running IE11 on Windows 7 in my environment, and we use this with no problem. Are you sure you're applying it to the right groups (user policy to users, or computer policy to computers)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention IE 11, I would like to bring up Enterprise Mode, which rolled out in April 2014's update.  It allows you to curate a list of sites, enforced by GPO, and have them run in a strict "IE8" layer.  At least, that's the short version.

The juicy part is the fact that the list is an XML file, you can set subdomains and paths.  See the example on Technet:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640696.aspx

When configured via GPO, IE 11 browsers will look to a URL for an XML file, and use that file's instructions to render sites in the appropriate mode.  I personally never got into IE Compatibility Modes, but so far I'm loving EMIE.  I can successfully run ***ancient*** ActiveX based intranet apps the the same browser as HTML5 tabs.

EMIE also allows tracking usage of the feature via a HTTP GET logger (IIS application).  If a site isn't on the list, and a user manually triggers Enterprise Mode, IE can be configured to send a notification to a URL.  The URL writes to a log, and this data can be used to refine additional sites for the EMIE XML list.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321457.aspx

It lists all the GP options for Comparability View.  Specifically, you want the one that turns on Compatibility View for selected websites.  It can be found under Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Compatability View

Answer (score 0):

I don't use group policy preferences because it keeps the users from updating their own list so I use the registry to force compatibility view. The problem with doing it this way is you cannot put a single site only a whole domain.

As a work around I had to get creative. In DNS I created a primary zone named Test. I then created an alias named Joe.Test and forwarded to a certain website. I then put the .test domain in compatibility view list.